# SwipeLayout ListView implementation in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating a `SwipeLayout ListView` and I'm trying to put it in a `fragment`, which is making me a problem. Just to mention, I have implemented tab layout (swiping to left/right disabled) and within this layout, I have 2 fragments (2 tabs).

I'm using this https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout for my SwipeLayout and in the example, it is implemented inside of an activity and not fragment which is a problem for me.

So I have `Activity.java` and `FragmentOne.java` and `ListAdapter.java`. Fragment is obviously child of the activity and so since I'm trying to implement that `SwipeLayout` into fragment, problem occurs when I put functions `setupList()` and `createList()` in the fragment and then I need to call `setupList()` but where should I call it? It will work if I override `onStart` but is that okay? Can it cause problems?

In the example, it is called in `onCreate` method which fragments do not have, and I can't call it in `onCreateView` because the view is not created yet and I need to have `list_view` ready. `list_view` is in `fragment.xml`.

I have also tried to implement these functions in `Activity` but I can't or I shouldn't access fragments layout elements from `Activity`, if I'am correct, as it isn't a good practice or not even possible.

```
private void setupList() {
    ListView listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), createList(20));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private List<String> createList(int n) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        list.add("View " + i);
    }

    return list;
}
```

What do I need to do to get this right? Is it necessary to implement the functionality in the fragment or is there some other way? I also have other fragments in that activity which kind of interact with each other, depending what will user do.